# Project which created on Xcode 6 is not shown as full screen

Tags: xcode, size-classes

I'm considering to convert my old projects which used xibs to storyboard. I created a new project to test size classes and just run on the simulator(iPhone 5s(7.1)) but screen is not a full screen.

[image]

Even I turned the size classes option off, the symptom's still exist. Why does it happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have a launch screen set up for that device? If you don't, it'll assume the 5S screen size is not supported.

Comment: @rickerbh yes I have one which created by Xcode wizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the answer. iOS 7.x does not support `LaunchScreen.xib`. After I added a `Default-568h@2x.png`, `Default.png`, `Default@2x.png`, the screen is full.